# is there any problem if I give Z-index =99999999999

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a widget. So it needs to appear on top of other pages. When I add the widget onto other websites,

I see that sometimes, other widgets come on top of my widget or some elements on the page come on top of it.

There are 2 solutions, I am thinking of.

1. Give a very big number to the z-index value like 99999999999. Is this a good approach?
2. Identify the biggest z-index number. And then adding on top of it? Which is a better approach?

Comment: You can go ahead and add a really high z index but that’s a common trick so someone else might be doing the same. Another issue is that it doesn’t always work. You need to know what a stacking context is.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't give any long number for z-index. The range of the `z-index` is `±2147483647`. (For 32 bit operating systems)

A very big number for CSS is perhaps a lazy way to ensure that the element is always on top. It can lead to problems down the road when multiple elements need to be on top.

My recommendation would be to check the context and then apply the z-index value and I would go for underlying layer + 1 option(Option 2 in your OP).